# Is it okay to send an array of objects to vertex shader?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, webgl, vertex-shader

Due to performance issues drawing thousands of similar triangles (with different attributes), I would like to draw all of these using a single call to drawElements. But in order to draw each triangle with their respective attributes (ex: world location, color, orientation) I believe i need to send an array buffer to my vertex shader, where the array is a list of all the triangle attributes.

If this approach is indeed the standard way to do it, then i am delighted to know i have the theory correct. I just need to know how to send an array buffer to the shader. Note that currently i know how to send a multiple attributes and uniforms (though they are not contiguous in memory, which is what im looking for).

If not, i'd appreciate it if a resident expert can point me in the right direction.

I have a related question because I am having trouble actually implementing a VBO.
[How to include model matrix to a VBO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24627445/how-to-include-model-matrix-to-a-vbo)

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for Vertex Buffer Objects (VBOs)  A quick google of this VBO and OpenGL ES 2.0 yields all sorts of samples.

Comment: I am still very much cloudy/confused on how to implement this. I need a conceptual example/tutorial/diagram/detailed-explanation. To be specific, if i have a single buffer with multiple objects, how will the vertex shader know which "object index" it is currently on (or is this automatic/transparent from the developer)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have the theory correct, let me just clear a few things...

You can only "send vertex array" to the vertex shader via pointers using attributes so this part of the code stays pretty much the same. What you do seem to be looking for are 2 optimisations, putting the whole buffer on the GPU and using interleaved vertex data.

To put the whole buffer on the GPU you need to use VBOs as already mentioned in the comment. By doing that you create a raw buffer on the GPU to which you can put any data you want and even modify them in runtime if needed. In your case that would be vertex data. To use non interleaved data you would probably create a buffer for each, position, colour, orientation...

To use interleaved data you need to put them into the buffer sequentially, if possible it is best to create a data structure that holds all the vertex data (of a single vertex, not the whole array) and send those to the buffer (a simple primitive array will work as well). A C example of such structure:

```
typedef union {
    struct {
        float x,y,z; //position
        float r,g,b,a; //color
        float ox,oy,oz; //orientation
    };
    struct {
        float position[3];
        float color[4];
        float orientation[3];
    };
}Vertex;
```

What you need to do then is set the correct pointers when using this data. In the VBO you start with `NULL` (0) and that would represent the position in this case, to set colour you would have to then use `((float *)NULL)+3` or use some conveniences such as `offsetof(Vertex, color)` in C. With that you also need to set the stride, that would be the size of the `Vertex` structure so you could use `sizeof(Vertex)` or hardcoded `sizeof(float)*(3+4+3)`.

After this all you need to watch for is correct buffer binding/unbinding while rest of your code should be exactly the same.

Comment: The is the most detailed explanation ive seen for VBOs. Unfortunately it is still vague. Can you please provide a working example or online references?

Comment: Specifically, i need an example of sending an array of data objects to the VBO buffer. Also, when should such data be sent to the buffer - every render cycle, or once during init-time?

Comment: Those data will persist until you explicitly delete them. If possible try to create this array when initialising. You can send the data directly when creating the buffer via glBufferData but this data parameter can be NULL and you can send the data later. Other means are then using subData or getting a direct pointer to the data where you can den do whatever you wish. I hope this might help clear a few things: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_Buffer_Object