# How to include model matrix to a VBO?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, webgl, vbo, vertex-buffer

I want to send a buffer list (to the GPU/vertex shader) which contains information about vertex position, world position, color, scale, and rotation.

If each of my 3D objects have transformation related information in a matrix, how can i pass this array of matrices (in addition to the other vertex data) to the GPU via the VBO(s) ?

**Updated**
Please excuse any typos:

```
// bind & set vertices.
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
gl.vertexAtribPointer(a_Position, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, stride, 0);

// bind & set vertex normals.
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,, vertexNormalsBuffer);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(a_Normal, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, stride, 0);

// becaue i cant pass in a model matrix via VBO, im tryng to pass in my world coordinates.
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, worldPositionBuffer);

// not sure why i need to do this, but most tutorials i've read says to do this.
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);

// bind & draw index buffer.
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexIndexBuffer);
gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, vertexIndexCount, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

Note that these buffers (`vertexBuffer`, `vertexNormalsBuffer`, `worldPostiionBuffer`, `vertexIndexBuffer`) are a concatenation of all the respective 3D objects in my scene (which i was rendering one-by-one via attributes/uniforms - a naive approach which is much simpler and easier to grasp, yet horribly slow for 1000's objects).

Comment: typically one would set the model matrix in a uniform and change it between models

Comment: i have 3d objects that can vary in translation, rotation, and scale (all contained by the model matrix). So im thinking each object has its own respective model matrix.

Comment: but each model has a lot of triangles, so just set the model matrix uniform for the first model, draw the triangles of the first model set the model matrix for the second, draw the triangles of the second, rinse repeat

Comment: I guess i need to clarify, because what you explained is what i'm doing (but it is very slow). Right now i am trying to make a single draw call using VBO(s). So all of my vertex information is in a single vertex buffer (e.g. for 1000's triangles).

Comment: Having banging my head on the desk, i think im going to pass in the world position as part of the VBO (instead of the model matrices).

Comment: @AlvinfromDiaspar: How about you show us your existing code. If you have trouble with as few as 1000 triangles, you're likely doing something wrong.

Comment: Are you for some strange unknown reason trying to have a matrix for each and every triangle you are drawing?

Comment: Matic, no. To elaborate my scene, i have quads and cubes. Each shape is an object. Currently i only have 1 model matrix which i reset and update per object render. This model matrix is a uniform.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For any values that you need to change frequently while rendering a frame, it can be more efficient to pass them into the shader as an `attribute` instead of a `uniform`. This also has the advantage that you can store the values in a VBO if you choose. Note that it's not *required* to store attributes in VBOs, they can also be specified with `glVertexAttrib[1234]f()` or `glVertexAttrib[1234]fv()`.

This applies to the transformation matrix like any other value passed into the shader. If it changes very frequently, you should probably make it an attribute. The only slight wrinkle in this case is that we're dealing with a matrix, and attributes have to be vectors. But that's easy to overcome. What is normally passed in as a `mat4` can be represented by 3 values of type `vec4`, where these 3 vectors are the column vectors of the matrix. It would of course be 4 vectors to represent a fully generic 4x4 matrix, but the 4th column in a transformation matrix is not used for any common transformation types (except for projection matrices).

If you want the transformations to be in the VBO, you set up 3 more attributes, the same way you already did for your positions and colors. The values of the attributes you store in the VBO are the column vectors of the corresponding transformation matrix.

Then in the vertex shader, you apply the transformation by calculating the dot product of the transformation attribute vectors with your input position. The code could look like this:

```
attribute vec4 InPosition;
attribute vec4 XTransform;
attribute vec4 YTransform;
attribute vec4 ZTransform;
main() {
    vec3 eyePosition = vec3(
        dot(XTransform, InPosition),
        dot(YTransform, InPosition),
        dot(ZTransform, InPosition));
    ...
}
```

There are other approaches to solve this problem in full OpenGL, like using Uniform Buffer Objects. But for WebGL and OpenGL ES 2.0, I think this is the best solution.

Comment: You mentioned "Note that it's not required to store attributes in VBOs, they can also be specified with glVertexAttrib*() calls.". Now, it is my understanding that after doing a bindBuffer i still need to call vertexAttribPointer, even for setting up a VBO. Is this not correct?

Comment: Sorry, that wildcard I used for the function names matches more than I intended. It was supposed to stand for functions like `glVertexAttrib3f()`, `glVertexAttrib4fv()`, etc. Yes, `glVertexAttribPointer()` is needed if you have the data in the VBO.

Comment: Whew... Thank God! Thanks again.

Comment: Why would this be more efficient? Now you would need to update the transform vectors for every single vertex in the mesh rather than a single uniform. It also seems like a huge waste of memory, which could add up very quickly for detailed meshes.

Comment: @Homar. From what i've read, draw calls should be minimized when making thousands of calls that render similar objects. So instead of 1k draw calls, i would like to make a single draw and let the GPU do any tranfsormation per object in the big VBO.

Comment: What you are referring to is called (static) batching. You can only do this if your objects do not move. You just modify your vertex positions in such cases in order to reduce draw calls (matrices/vectors not required). Note that draw calls are not themselves expensive. It's the state changes that are expensive. State changes are deferred until you make the draw call. If your objects are not static then I don't see how you benefit from the method described above.

Comment: If your objects are static, then just modify the vertex positions by multiplying them by the model transformation matrix. This will save you memory. If you have many instances of the same object (just with different world space positions, orientations and scales), then use instanced rendering.

Comment: @Homar: The question posed was how to have transformation matrices in a VBO. That's what I answered. I don't think it's possible to know what the fastest solution for the OP's use case is without implementing at least 4 or 5 different approaches, and comparing on a variety of platforms. But the idea of this site is really to answer specific questions.

Comment: @Homar, on your last comment: While I haven't used WebGL, I believe instanced rendering is not supported there, since it's based on ES 2.0.

Comment: There is alot of people saying VBO's can be modified using subdata buffer or submapping (or whatever these are called) which allows for partial VBO data updating.

Comment: Yes, but you would still need to update the three vectors for every single vertex in the mesh. If you have a mesh of n vertices than you will need to buffer 3*n 3D vectors if the object moves or rotates.

Comment: What exactly is `eyeposition`? can that be used as a `model` component of a `ModelViewProjection` ?

Answer (score -1):

Your method is correct and in someways unavoidable. If you have 1000 **different** objects that are **not static** then you will need to (or it is best to) make 1000 draw calls. However, if your objects are static then you can merge them together as long as they use the same material.

Merging static objects is simple. You modify the vertex positions by multiplying by the model matrix in order to transform the vertices into world space. You then render the batch in a single draw call.

If you have many instances of the same object but with different model matrices (i.e. different positions, orientations or scales) then you should use instanced rendering. This will allow you to render all the instances in a single draw call.

Finally, note that draw calls are not necessarily expensive. What happens is that state changes are deferred until you issue your draw call. For example, consider the following:

```
gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, vertexIndexCount, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, vertexIndexCount, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

The second draw call will be much less taxing on the CPU than the second (try it for yourself). This is because there are no state changes between the two draw calls. If you are just updating the model matrix uniform variable between draw calls then that shouldn't add significantly to the cost. It is possible (and recommended) to minimize state changes by sorting your objects by shader program and by material.

Comment: Updating uniforms can be quite expensive on some platforms. I would certainly expect it to be at least as expensive as other typical state changes, likely more expensive. They are called **uniform** for a good reason, because they're not expected to be modified frequently. As I mentioned in my earlier comment, instanced rendering is not available on the platform used by the OP.

Comment: Does uniform necessarily mean "no frequent modification"? I thought it meant uniform for all vertices in a buffer (as opposed to attributes which apply on a per vertex basis).

Comment: From what i've read, draw calls are expensive when working with 1000's and 1000's of objects. Of course minimizing state changes helps as well.

Comment: Updating one matrix uniform is always going to be faster than sending over one matrix per vertex. So the cost is irrelevant as the alternatives are going to be far worse.

Comment: But regarding state changes, when i was making N draw calls for N objects, the only thing i was setting was the bindings and setting of attributes (vertex position and color) and uniforms (model matrix) per object. Where N > 2500 objects, i was seeing around 5 fps.

Comment: Also, updating uniforms is about the lest expensive state change you can make. There was a comparison posted somewhere on here if you can find it.

Comment: I'm not sure what platform you are working on so I can't say whether those figures are to be expected. You will may get slightly better performance using Retro Koradi's method as long as you update your model matrices extremely infrequently, but you will be take a significant memory hit. The only way to find out is to try both and profile.

Comment: Don't believe everything you read on the internet. I've seen major game titles fighting with performance problems due to updating uniforms too frequently. I'm sure that it *can* be fast on some platforms under some circumstances, but that doesn't mean that it's universally true.

Comment: Right now my bottleneck (i believe) is sending data to the GPU for every object that i want to draw in a scene. I know I can sort and draw them in a smart order, thus reducing the "state changes". I want to do as much as I possibly can on the GPU, AND I want to draw many objects as I can in minimal draw calls. Also, i'd consume more memory for better performance any day.