# OpenglES 2.0 Matrices as vertex attributes

Tags: matrix, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to send matrices by vertex instead by uniform so that the program is a bit faster. The problem is that my objects doesn't appear and I don't understand why. For vertices and colors I always do like that and it always works.

here is the code :

```
GLuint _mbo[4];
_camera->getMatricies(projection, view, model);
glm::vec4 column0 = glm::column(view, 0);
glm::vec4 column1 = glm::column(view, 1);
glm::vec4 column2 = glm::column(view, 2);
glm::vec4 column3 = glm::column(view, 3);

std::cerr << glm::to_string(column0) << std::endl;
glGenBuffers(1, &_mbo[0]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _mbo[0]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 4 * sizeof(GLfloat), &column0[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

std::cerr << glm::to_string(column1) << std::endl;
glGenBuffers(1, &_mbo[1]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _mbo[1]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 4 * sizeof(GLfloat), &column1[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

std::cerr << glm::to_string(column2) << std::endl;
glGenBuffers(1, &_mbo[2]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _mbo[2]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 4 * sizeof(GLfloat), &column2[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

std::cerr << glm::to_string(column3) << std::endl;
glGenBuffers(1, &_mbo[3]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _mbo[3]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 4 * sizeof(GLfloat), &column3[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

.....

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _mbo[0]);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(matId);
glVertexAttribPointer(matId, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _mbo[1]);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(matId + 1);
glVertexAttribPointer(matId + 1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _mbo[2]);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(matId + 2);
glVertexAttribPointer(matId + 2, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _mbo[3]);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(matId + 3);    
glVertexAttribPointer(matId + 3, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
```

the vertex shader :

```
#version 100

attribute vec3 position;
attribute vec3 color;
attribute vec2 texcoord;

attribute mat4 view;
varying vec3 vColor;
varying vec2 vTex;

uniform mat4 projection;
//uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 model;

varying vec2 v_uv;

void main(){
  // mat4 test;
  // test[0] = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  // test[1] = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  // test[2] = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
  // test[3] = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

  gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(position, 1.0);
  vColor = color;
  vTex = texcoord;
}
```

I cannot determinate if the problem happen in the shader or not ... It's very frustrating for me.

Comment: @Rabbid76 from this site, it says that an attribute mat4  generates 4 vertex attributes (vec4 each). But I tested with 4 vertex of vec4 nothing displayed too ...

Comment: No, for now I have a triangle, this matrix is the view matrix from camera.

Comment: Oh ok ... It will not be fun ... 
Last question please, so that mean when we use glUniform, this function set the matrix data alone on each vertex, is it correct ?

Comment: Hmm sorry this is really the last question and I stop bothering you. I read that passing the transformation matrix via attribute accelerates the rendering but how it can accelerate it if we have to set the data to each vertex ?

Comment: @Rabbid76 I read it on this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24627445/how-to-include-model-matrix-to-a-vbo and on some others website

Comment: Okay thanks, I knew it's more efficient with values changing frequently but I tested with the view matrix because it's more simple. 
Anyway, thank you very much for answering my questions :)

Comment: vertex attributes in GLSL may change between vertices, but you can load a single value from OpenGL like a uniform. I believe this is preferrable when an attribute is sometimes uniform, sometimes different, changing programs is a pain and bandwidth is terrible. gles-2.0 targets wooden platforms.